# Make same animation happen each time a particular element is clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm quite new to jQuery and for this bit of code I've been working with animated.css

I've got my animation working so that on click my object animates
with this code: (which i used based on another question asked on stack-overflow)

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('animated swing').removeClass('animated swing');
$(this).addClass('animated swing');
});
```

However when you click again nothing happens. 
I looked into getting the js to listen out for the animation end using variables then removing a class, but that doesn't seem to work either. Perhaps my syntax is all wrong - or do i need to toggle the animation on off click?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you need to change the code a little bit. You forgot the CSS class selector `.`:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.animated.swing').removeClass('animated swing');
  $(this).addClass('animated swing');
});
```

Try this and 1000% it should work! `:)`

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('.animated.swing').removeClass('animated swing');
    $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
      $this.addClass('animated swing');
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css" />
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

I have added a `setTimeout` for the demo to show something realistic. `:)`